# Pegar valor de input HTML e passar para variável em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Possuo esse seguinte input:

```
    <p>Início do período:</p> <input type="text" id="calendario">

    <script>
    var start = new Date(1997, 12, 01);
    var end = new Date(1998, 11, 31) ;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendario').datepicker({
           startDate: start,
           endDate: end
        });
    });
</script>
```

necessito do valor que o usuário irá selecionar, como conseguiria colocar esse valor em uma variável php?

Comment: Agora está melhor ;)

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu queria como resposta, de uma editada que coloquei o código das propriedades, mas te respondendo aqui, vou pegar o valor da data para colocar em um select.

Comment: poderia exemplificar aqui pra mim @Raizant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="calendario" name="calendario">
```

Adicione um name a seu  campo
no  php  você pode pegar  via $_POST ou $_GET depende do metodo que vai enviar para o  serivodor

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['calendario'])){
    $calendario = $_POST['calendario'];
}
?>
```

Seu formulario deve ficar parecido com isso

```
<form method="post" action="urlp do seu site">
    <input type="text" id="calendario" name="calendario">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: não entendi muito bem essa parte do formulário, seria como eu iria exibir o calendário para o usuário e pegar o valor em html?

Comment: testei aqui o seu código... Na verdade o que eu vou querer é que o usuário entre com a data de inicio e de fim, pq o meu select tem será em relação a um período, então o submit terá que pegar o valor de 2 inputs, eu deveria acrescentar um outro calendario ali então ficaria :
<form method="post" url="urlp do seu site">
    <input type="text" id="calendario1" name="calendario1">
  <input type="text" id="calendario2" name="calendario2">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>

assim, @Marcos Brinner pikatoons ?

Comment: isso vcoê que pegar o  valor de inicio e fim vindo do html para o  php  correto ? então é isso msm  vc so precisa criar mais um campo  html igua vc mencional  acima

Comment: uma última pergunta,  eu poderia fazer o submit fora da tag de form?

Comment: sim, mais ai vc vai ter que o  usaro  $("#formID").submit() pesquise pela função submit do jquery/javascript

Comment: testei o código com o 2º input aqui e não deu certo, não apareceu o calendario com as propriedades do datepicker... outra dúvida: o url receberia o caminho da raiz até a pasta onde está a pagina?

Comment: vc vai  ter  que chamar  o  datapicker  novamente para o outro campo  $("#calendario2").datepicker(); em seu javascript

Comment: vc vai  receber os dados na  mesma pagina ? se for não defina  defina action="" se for para outra pagina defina action="//seustie.com/pagina/caminho.php"

Comment: não é url eu havia colocado errado é action

Comment: é tudo na mesma página, para vc entender melhor, o problema é o seguinte: eu tenho que pegar a data de início e data de fim para determinar um período e fazer um select, depois que o usuário selecionar as datas vou exibir uma tabela com o que o meu select retornar. Isso tudo na mesma página.